My dad is Dutch, I was born outside the Netherlands and never lived there. Am I still Dutch?
I am 42, my father is Dutch but I have a Philippines passport and I never lived in the Netherlands. Am I a Dutch citizen? Can I acquire Dutch nationality?

You may well be Dutch, but it depends on many factors including your parents' status at the time of your birth and your age.  When were you born?  Was your mother married to your father?  What was her nationality?  Did your father ever naturalize in the Philippines or elsewhere?  Did you naturalize in the Philippines or elsewhere?  Etc., etc.

Im 42, my parents never married, My father is still dutch, and how does the nationality by descent works?

I edited some of this information in your question. There are still a couple of details requested by @phoog that are missing: Namely your parents' status (and I guess especially your father's) at the time of your birth, were they residents in the country where you were born, etc. and how you became a Philippines citizen (is it your mother's citizenship?)

In general, nationality by descent is not about “becoming” anything. There are numerous nuances and exceptions depending on the country (and phoog knows Dutch law on this much better than myself) but typically you inherit one or more citizenships at birth. So the real question is whether you were Dutch when you were born (hence the questions on your parents' exact status) and whether you lost it later on (that's where naturalization comes in for example).

Basically you need to establish that you were Dutch when you were born and that you haven't lost Dutch nationality since then.  Since you were born before the current nationality law came into effect in 1985, and your parents never married, you would be Dutch if and only if your father had formally "legitimated" or "acknowledged" you as his child.  Did he?

Even if he did, you probably lost Dutch nationality under the former ten year rule, which starts counting on your 18th birthday, which was I suppose in late 1999 or early 2000, if I am not mistaken.  The 10 year period would have reset in 2003 when the conditions of the rule were changed by an amendment, meaning that if you were Dutch from birth you likely lost your Dutch nationality in 2013.  But there are several exceptions to the 10-year rule.  They won't apply to most people but they might apply to you.  In any event the first question is that of acknowledgement or legitimation.

Voting to close because there’s no evidence of any prior research by the OP, and key information mentioned in comments posted two days ago is still missing.
